# Deleting from SQL database using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

hi I'm having troubles regarding  the window alert of my program. it always show 'no record found in the database'  but it successfully delete the row. asking for a hand here. thanks!

```
try
            {
                con.Open();
                string Sql = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE LastName LIKE '" + txtbx_delete.Text + "'";

                MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(Sql, con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds);


                if (ds.Tables.Count > 0 && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Delete successful! Check display!')", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('No record with that last name found!')", true);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Yeah. COMMON SENSE: How would a DELETE statement load data into a DataSet? Just asking. Because in my world (which, grante, does not use MySQL) DELETE does NOT generate a output.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [`ExecuteNonQuery()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx) instead for Adapter Which gives you the number of rows affected, based on that you can throw the message; and probably [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i) are better option to avoid injection(more impotent since you are dealing with delete).

```
  string Sql = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE LastName LIKE @delete";
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(readCommand))
   {
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("@delete", txtbx_delete.Text));  
    int result= m.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //result holds number of rows affected 
    if (result>0)
     {
      ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Delete successful! Check display!')", true);
     }
    else
     {
       ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('No record with that last name found!')", true);
     }
   }
```

Always try to make use of the `using` statement to dispose of the objects correctly.
You can try it for connections also, it will drop the connection instantly after using it.

Comment: where should i put that on my code. im sorry im just new in this language. trying m best to catch up.

Comment: Should be `int result = m.ExecuteNonQuery();`.  @AlphiCanoza you replace your `if` statement with `if (result > 0)`.

Comment: @Brad: absolutely; I have made that updates to the answer

Answer (score 2):

This is because you don't fetch the table. You are simply running a delete query.